# Subsonic Complex SQL conditional statements - Condition1 And (( Condition2 And Condition3) OR (Condition4 And Condition5))

Tags: subsonic

How do I build a query in Subsonic that of this format:

Condition1 And (( Condition2 And Condition3) OR (Condition4 And Condition5))

The originial SQL Query is:

`SELECT * 
FROM Events 
WHERE Deleted=false 
AND ((DateModified IS NOT NULL AND DateModified BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2) OR (DateModified IS NULL AND DateCreated BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2))`

I've tried arious approaches, using AndExpreession(), OrExpression(), OpenExpression(),  CloseExpression() but I cant seem to get the desired result.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Which version of SubSonic do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that particular query, why not get rid of all the parenthesis and simply let the operator precedence take over:

Condition1 And Condition2 And Condition3 OR Condition1 And Condition4 And Condition5